# Update Jenkins 1 to 2 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: jenkins, raspberry-pi

finally i got my raspberry pi 3. I installed jenkins via

> sudo apt-get install jenkins
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start

After the installation, I was able to connect to the server (localhost: 8080). Now i wanted to configure the Jenkins with new build jobs, but i realized i need to get the new Version (Jenkins 2). I downloaded the new .war-File from

> wget http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/2.32.2/jenkins.war

and replaced it with the old one in /usr/share/jenkins

After

> sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart

and connect to localhost:8080 i got no response. If i replaced the original .war-file i can connect to localhost:8080 (version 1.5).

I have already restarted my raspberry pi.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Now i solved the problem:

The downloaded .war-File was correct. I don't know why, but if i replace the war file it doesn't work.

simple solution:

java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=

of the new .war-file and it works.